# How to get different data from two different tables in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-query-store

I have two table named **Soft** and **Web**, table containing multiple data in that which data is different that data I want. For Ex :

In soft table containing 5 data i.e.

[image]

Also in Web table containing 5 data i.e.

[image]

Now I want output i.e.

[image]

I have done query but unfortunately didnt succed, lets see my query i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT soft.GSTNo AS SoftGST
    ,web.GSTNo AS WebGST
    ,soft.InvoiceNumber AS SoftInvoice
    ,web.InvoiceNumber AS WebInvoice
    ,soft.Rate AS SoftRate
    ,web.Rate AS WebRate
FROM soft
LEFT OUTER JOIN web ON web.GstNo = soft.GSTNo
    AND web.InvoiceNumber = soft.invoicenumber
    AND web.rate = soft.rate
```

Also I apply inner join bt same thing didnt work.

Comment: why you 321 and 121 is not included in your desired output..

Comment: @AjeetVerma bcos 321 and 121 is common data in both table and I want output of different data

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by

```
;WITH cte_soft AS
    (SELECT * FROM soft 
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT * FROM web) 
    ,cte_web AS
    (SELECT * FROM web
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT * FROM soft)
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT gst softgst, NULL webgst, invoice softinvoice, NULL webinvoice, rate softrate, NULL webrate
   FROM cte_soft
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT NULL, gst, NULL, invoice, NULL , rate
   FROM cte_web) tbl
ORDER BY coalesce(softgst, webgst),coalesce(softinvoice,webinvoice)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ee247920082640f6f9c47c431c855d85)

Comment: ,same query I was going to post for this solution ,but you post first ...from prospective it's a good solution ...one up vote from my side ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join`:

```
SELECT s.gst as softgst, w.gst as webgst,
       s.invoice as softinvoice, w.invoice as webinvoice,
       s.rate as softrate, w.rate as webrate
FROM soft s FULL JOIN
     web w
     ON s.gst = w.gst AND s.invoice = w.invoice AND s.rate = w.rate
WHERE s.gst IS NULL OR w.gst IS NULL
ORDER BY COALESCE(s.gst, w.gst), COALESCE(s.invoice, w.invoice);
```

No subqueries are CTEs are needed.  This is really just a slight variant of your query.